# How to hibernate/suspend rapberry pi?

Tags: raspbian

I have a RPi connected to TV via it's USB port to display statistics graphs. Every morning I have to power it up and set up the chrome tabs which consumes lots of time. I was looking for a way to safely hibernate or suspend by saving state in the evening so the following morning I only have to boot it up.

Leaving the TV on all night is not an option.

Comment: It's in theory possible to hibernate but you will need to compile a custom kernel, as last I checked the stock one does not include that.

Comment: There is NO support with ANY Raspberry for hibernate or suspend. The hardware isn't configured for that.

Comment: @Dougie **Hibernate does not require hardware support,** but it does require a swap partition at least the size of the RAM.  When you hibernate the current memory image is stored in the swap partition.  A `restore=` parameter to the kernel command line indicates the location of the swap partition, and when it boots, it checks to see if there is a saved image there.  If so, it loads that image into userspace RAM and presto, state is restored....

Comment: *However*: I did later try this and it did not work. I did not bother to drill down and find out why/if some workaround is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi4 systemctl suspend or systemctl hibernated not supported?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111409/raspberry-pi4-systemctl-suspend-or-systemctl-hibernated-not-supported)

Answer (score 1):

is switching only the TV off and leaving the Pi running an option for you? I have a couple running this way - one with OMV and one with Pi-Hole. this way you can also reach the Pi via SSh or VNC from your laptop for example. Another option would be to simply disconnect the TV and connect via VNC from another computer.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempt to hibernate, I'd make a script that does nothing but "set up the chrome tabs" and whatever else you do after boot up that "consumes lots of time"

While the pi does not have an easy hibernate to disk, it has many ways to automate tasks.  Personally I'd attach starting chrome to the loading of the desktop environment.  Others may have fancier solutions with systemd.

Answer (score -2):

Try sudo systemctl hibernate
You could also suspend it if you wanted to with sudo systemctl suspend

Comment: It says `Failed to suspend system via logind: Sleep verb "suspend" not supported` or `Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb "hibernate" not supported`. I am using ArchLinux ARM.